# Update SQL if row's time is 5 minutes or longer than now

Tags: mysql, sql, date, time, sql-update

I want to update SQL in which row's time is 5 minutes ago (or longer than 5 minutes):

```
UPDATE mytable SET status='EXPIRED' 
WHERE (a column's time is 5 minutes or longer before now)
```

I tried to use `DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)` but I had no luck!

Comment: What is "*row's time*"? are you keeping that somehow?

Comment: Is it a datetime column (or) INT type column. Explain more.

Comment: There has to be some kind of activity date/time object in the row as part of the table, populated on last update/insert

Comment: The column's name is "time_sent" and the format is set using date("H:i:s") PHP function. I want to compare it with Now and if time_sent is for example 12:51:30 and now = 12:58:30 (where now is more than 5 minute compared to time_sent) update the row.

Comment: @Rahul its TIME (not datatime)

Comment: So you are not storing the date?

Comment: @Uueerdo No, its only about the time!

Comment: How do you handle midnight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare `now()` with the row's date column plus 5 minutes:

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET    status = 'EXPIRED' 
WHERE  DATE_ADD(date_col, INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) <= NOW()
```

Comment: Assuming date_col is a DATE/DATETIME/TIMESTAMP, performing a date_sub on NOW, instead of DATE_ADD on the field, should be much faster.

Comment: Thank you, I worked. I just changed >= to <= and changed TIME type to DATETIME to handle midnights! (thanks to @Uueerdo)

Comment: It would be more efficient to perform the function on NOW - oh, that's what ueerdo said

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but considering that your time column is of `DATETIME` you can use `BETWEEN` operator like below

```
UPDATE mytable SET status='EXPIRED' 
WHERE your_time_column BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -5 MINUTE) AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
```

Answer (score 1):

A typical way would use `date_sub()`:

```
UPDATE mytable
    SET status = 'EXPIRED'
    WHERE <columntime> < date_sub(now(), interval 5 minute);
```

You can also use `date_add()` with a negative number of units.  Also, you should put the function call on `now()` rather than on the column, so MySQL can take advantage of an index on the column, if appropriate.